# Kafka Snowflake Connector - Stopping after connector error

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-connector

I've been checking all the kafka snowflake connector posts but none of them talked about the issue I'm having.

I installed Kafka in local, with zookeper, and I also want to run a Snowflake connector, to copy data from Kafka towards Snowflake.

I run zookeeper, every thing looks right:

[zookeeper log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peZgN.png)

Then I launch the kafka server, looks correct as well:

[server log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzikk.png)

However when I launch the snowflake-kafka-connector:

```
sh connect-standalone.sh /usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/config/connect-standalone.properties /usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/config/SF_connect.properties
```

, it breaks like this:

**[2022-05-27 10:41:37,380] INFO Finished creating connector TEST_CONNECTOR (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:224)
[2022-05-27 10:41:37,380] INFO Skipping reconfiguration of connector kafkatest since it is not running (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:285)
[2022-05-27 10:41:37,381] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:113)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.entities.ConnectorInfo.name()" because the return value of "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Herder$Created.result()" is null
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone$1.onCompletion(ConnectStandalone.java:104)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone$1.onCompletion(ConnectStandalone.java:98)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.onCompletion(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:44)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:185)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:107)
[2022-05-27 10:41:37,382] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:65)
[2022-05-27 10:41:37,382] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:211)**

I tried to find information on what's the matter, but I can't find anything. Can you please help me on that?

This is the sf_connector.properties file:

[sf_connector.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiDvA.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like something in your configuration file is not correct.

Comment: Can you post the content of SF_connect.properties with data masked where needed?

Comment: NPE in Connect could be a bug. I suggest installing a newer version of Kafka

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post attaching the sf_connect.properties file:

Comment: I'm using the latest version: kafka_2.11-1.1.0

Comment: Hey, managed to override the error by updating the Java SE, but now I get another one... and also there's not much info about that one...  Cannot invoke "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.entities.ConnectorInfo.name()" because the return value of "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Herder$Created.result()" is null

Comment: Finally it was a matter of the kafka server version